# How to find the result after converting string categories to integers?

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
data=pd.read_excel('car_data1.xlsx')
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

le=LabelEncoder()
for i in data.columns:
  data[i]=le.fit_transform(data[i])

%matplotlib inline
```

This data is downloaded from https://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Car+Evaluation

My question is that why I cannot see anything about the result after I run this code in the Python?

I hope I can get the output as follows:

buying  maint   doors   persons lug_boot    safety  class

0   3   3   0   0   2   1   2

1   3   3   0   0   2   2   2

2   3   3   0   0   2   0   2

3   3   3   0   0   1   1   2

4   3   3   0   0   1   2   2

Comment: um, I think it's because you didn't `print` it?

Comment: what output you are expecting where you have written the code to show the output

Comment: @ppwater I wrote `data.head()` but nothing happens...

Comment: Try `print(data.head())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because you didn't `print` it.

You can try `print(data.head())`

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
data=pd.read_excel('car_data1.xlsx')
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

le=LabelEncoder()
for i in data.columns:
  data[i]=le.fit_transform(data[i])

%matplotlib inline
print(data.head())
```